# Flask internal redirect: url_for vs normal href?

Tags: flask

I am new to Flask and I would like to know what is the best practice to set up internal redirect. For example, I do have this block of code in my `templates/register.html`

```
<div>
    <p> Already have an account? <a href="/login">login here</a><p>
</div>
```

**main.py**

```
@app.route('/login')
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    return render_template("login.html", title='Login', form=form)
```

I am wondering if it's a better practice to use the `url_for` instead and why?

```
<div>
    <p> Already have an account? <a href="{{ url_for("login")}}">login here</a><p>
</div>
```

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `url_for()` command generate url address of function, so it is better, because you might change route of function in future, but you won't change name of the function (or less times then url address). This method is more reliable and has more benefits.

Answer (score 1):

[`url_for()`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/api/#flask.Flask.url_for) would be better in place of **href**, because
if you change the URL in future, all you have to do is change your **URL** in one file.
If you use `href="/login"`, then you have to change it in all your files.